# Pagination Links in Yii2 Rest API Custom Action Response

Tags: rest, pagination, yii2, api-design

I have created my own object/index action in a yii rest controller which does some simple things:

```
public function actionIndex($name){
                $query = Object::find();
                $count = $query->count();
               
                $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount'=>$count]);
                $objectList = $query->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit)->all();
                return $objectList;
    }
```

When I make a request to: http://localhost:8443/v0/objects?name=warehouse&page=1&per-page=1 I receive the following response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data": {
            "city": "Test",
            "name": "ABC Warehouse",
            "postal_code": "M1F 4F2",
            "street_address": "1234 Street",
            "owner": 76,
            "created_at": "2016-09-23 15:10:20",
            "updated_at": "2017-07-27 11:56:15",
            "created_by": 9,
            "updated_by": 13
        },
        "displayData": []
    }
]
```

I would like to include the pagination link information as shown here but am not sure how to go about this
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
X-Pagination-Total-Count: 1000
X-Pagination-Page-Count: 50
X-Pagination-Current-Page: 1
X-Pagination-Per-Page: 20
Link: <http://localhost/users?page=1>; rel=self, 
      <http://localhost/users?page=2>; rel=next, 
      <http://localhost/users?page=50>; rel=last
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using the yii\rest\ActiveController

A quick look into the yii2 source suggests (to me) that whatever is returned need to implement the yii\data\DataProviderInterface. Right now your code does not return the Pagination object at all to be handled.

Assuming you're Object extends ActiveRecord, try this in your action...

```
public function actionIndex($name){
    $query = Object::find();  // Assumes Object extends ActiveRecord
    $countQuery = clone $query;  // Good idea to clone query
    $count = $countQuery->count();
    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount'=>$count]);
    $query->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit);        
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => $pagination,        
    ]);
}
```

Note, this code is NOT tested. Hopefully it will help anyway.

--- Edit ---

Also in the yii\rest\ActiveController set this property (as suggested by Scott)

```
public $serializer = [
    'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
    'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help! Not sure why it is a good idea to clone the query object before doing a count - so I omitted that for now. Thank you Karpy.

Comment: I also had to add: 
        public $serializer = [
            'class'=>'yii\rest\Serializer',
            'collectionEnvelope'=>'items'
        ];
to my controller. If you could add this to your answer it would be helpful for other people.

Comment: Regarding cloning, it might not matter in this case, but since we're executing two queries on the same Query object, we don't know if the first query (->count) changes the Query object that is later used again (in the ActiveDataProvider). Seemed like a good idea to clone and separate the queries.

Comment: Didn't know about the collectionEnvelope, but you are right. It seems to be needed when returning meta/link toghether with data. Read more about it here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-response-formatting.html

Comment: Ya that does seem to be the case. Thanks for your help - our api is on its way!